How can I stop automatic submit after finishing all Input in a Form? (react-hook-form)
So I created a multi-step-form using shadcn, next, zod and react-hook-form. I have a problem wherein the form submitted on step 3 which is not what I want.
form.tsx
    const form = useForm<Inputs>({
        resolver: zodResolver(formSchemaData),
        defaultValues: {
          title: "",
          email: "",
          fullName: "",
          department: "",
          dateOfEvent: "",
          purpose: "",
          staringTime: "",
          endingTime: "",
          doesHaveDryRun: "",
          dryRunDate: "",
          dryRunStart: "",
          dryRunEnd: "",
        },
      });
    
      function onSubmit(values: any) {
        console.log(values);
      }
    
      const goToNextPage = async () => {
        const fields = steps[currentFormPage].fields;
        const output = await form.trigger(fields as FieldName[], {
          shouldFocus: true,
        });
    
        if (!output) return;
    
        if (currentFormPage < steps.length - 1) {
          setPreviousStep(currentFormPage);
          setCurrentFormPage((step) => step + 1);
        }
    
      };

So for example here. I didn't hit the next button yet so nothing is showing in my console.

But when I press the next button, the form console.log the data even though it should be on submit button.

This is the full code.

Set the type of next page button to button. If it is not defined, it's the type of submit by default, so you are always submitting the data when clicking it.
<Button variant="default" type="button" onClick={goToNextPage}>Next</Button>


I tried this but didn't work.

@Stykgwar add a preventDefault() for the mouseEvent into goToNextPage and check if still occurs.
